# Ready to use paint library

Tags: ios, uiview, drawing, paint

I'm in the search of an easy to use paint library.

I just want to say something like `- (void)drawLineWithColor:(UIColor *)color inView:(UIView *)view`.
I want to draw lines, free forms and some similar basic drawings.

I want to "activate" drawing via an UIButton and deactivate it by pressing again...
Is there any library or implementation that is so easy to use as I imagine?

I've read a lot on google about painting in iOS. But it seems so complicated to me, that I think somebody could have build some kind of very easy to use implementation...

Hope somebody knows something like this.

Thanks, kind regards, Julian

Comment: Why would it ever be easy?  Drawing takes a lot of work.

Comment: Why not? Check the implementation from Delphi, very easy and straightforward to be understood for lots of beginners. I agree with the author of topic, in iOS, is like in WinAPI a little complicated to get started, but after that, after you create some wrapper methods it gets easier :)

Answer (score 0):

If you haven't had a chance to look at [GLPaint](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/GLPaint/Introduction/Intro.html), I highly recommend it.  It may be a little complicated (GL is notoriously hard to learn), but it is a great learning experience.  The opening even literally draws the words 'shake to clear' on the screen, thus solving your requirement to draw on screen.  It draws in 4 colors (on last check).

Comment: I already had a look at GLPaint, thanks. I see, GL is hard to learn, for sure. I had a little hope that somebody ran into the same problem and might have solved this "problem" for the rest of the world :)